# Finding most dense rectangles in a numeric matrix using R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a question. I want to find the most dense squares in a numeric matrix. Suppose I have a matrix like this one:

```
A = matrix(c(0,20,100,44,0, 
         50,10,0,20,99,
         10,30,25,80,10,
         1,50,20,100,0,
         30,0,5,10,40), nrow=5, ncol=5)
```

This results to the following matrix:

```
>     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0   50   10    1   30
[2,]   20   10   30   50    0
[3,]  100    0   25   20    5
[4,]   44   20   80  100   10
[5,]    0   99   10    0   40
```

Now I would like to sort that matrix such that I get the quadratic fields that are most dense (have the highest combined value).

For an example, the resulting matrix should look something like this:

```
>    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   20   50   30   10    0
[2,]  100   20   25    0    5
[3,]   44  100   80   20   10
[4,]    0    1   10   50   30
[5,]    0    0   10   99   40
```

Where the two squares are the upper left square with length 3 and the bottom right square with a length of 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218253/sort-table-rows-columns-to-minimize-distance